# View Based Table View Within a View Based Table View

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I'm looking to create a Mac App in which you have a Table View within a Table View.

I used a View Based Table View and inside it's cellView, I've placed another Table View. So far, so good. I run the program and can see both table views working fine. I also created different Outlets for the tables but get a warning that says

```
warning: Unsupported Configuration: Outlet 'innerTable' of 'File's Owner' is connected to 'Table View,' an invalid destination (Object may be repeated at runtime.)
```

I looked the error up but couldn't get a definite answer.

My aim is to create something like the "Pulse" app available for iPhone / iPad.

Another thing:

When I make the inner Table View - View Based, without writing any code, I get this error:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

I cannot seem to control the inner Table View in any way.

Here's a screen shot of how things currently are in the xib.

```
![Screen shot that shows my xib](http://prntscr.com/zuic3)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem - it appears that referencing items inside an NSTableView (custom labels, text fields, anything that can commonly be referenced) will not work if it's inside a view based table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a demo project in the Apple documentation called TableViewPlayground. In it Apple demonstrate how to reference custom objects in the NSTableView. The demo shows three different examples, you want to look at the Complex Table View option.

Sadly the demo is totally undocumented, and the code is awkwardly written, but you can examine the connections in xib files and see what is subclassed and referenced and how the puzzle cites together, but perhaps it helps either way.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/TableViewPlayground/Introduction/Intro.html

I believe the way to create connections for custom cells is by NOT using the assistant editor - even though it's commonplace in iOS. Instead, declare your IBOutlets in code beforehand, then use the connections inspector to control-drag from the element in IB to your custom class. Doing so will prevent the "Unsupported Configuration" error.